# How to update a selection of SQL records from Access VB?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm looking for help in creating the simplest method of doing the following update on a selection of items.

I have a table in SQL called Item with field ReservationID

I have a list of items in Access and what I'd like to do is select items using the record selectors in the Access form and update those items with the ReservationID using an SQL Update command.

I read somewhere that only adjacent record selectors could be selected which is fine but I don't really know where to begin.

Any pointers would be gratefully received. Thanks.
---23/02/2017---
Ok I changed it from a function to a Private Sub thus:

```
Private Sub cmdReserve_Click()
 Dim i As Long
 Dim frm As Form
 Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
 ' Get the form and its recordset.
 Set frm = Forms![F_SalesOrders_ItemsInStock]
 Set rs = frm.RecordsetClone
 ' Move to the first record in the recordset.
 rs.MoveFirst
 ' Move to the first selected record.
 rs.Move frm.SelTop - 1
 ' Enumerate the list of selected records 
 ' presenting the field contents in a message box.
 For i = 1 To frm.SelHeight
   MsgBox rs![ItemID]
   rs.MoveNext
 Next i
End Sub
```

but when I select records and hit the button nothing happens

Comment: Are you using vb.net (the .Net Framework, maybe Visual Studio) or VBA (within office, maybe an access macro)?

Comment: I'm using Access 2010 as the front end and SQL Express for the DB

Answer (score 1):

Consider a linked table and walking the record set.

```
Function DisplaySelectedCompanyNames()
 Dim i As Long
 Dim frm As Form
 Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

 ' Get the form and its recordset.
 Set frm = Forms![Customers]
 Set rs = frm.RecordsetClone

 ' Move to the first record in the recordset.
 rs.MoveFirst

 ' Move to the first selected record.
 rs.Move frm.SelTop - 1

 ' Enumerate the list of selected records presenting
 ' the CompanyName field in a message box.
 For i = 1 To frm.SelHeight
   MsgBox rs![CompanyName]
   rs.MoveNext
 Next i

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Fionnuala. Unfortunately I'm really stretching my capabilities here and I'm not really understanding the aim of the code. I tried assigning a modified version of this to a button, selecting some records and clicking the button but it had no effect. I'm assuming it should have msgbox'ed me a message?

Comment: Did you change all the forms and column names to match your situation? Did you get an error message?

Comment: The important bits are seltop and selheight.

Comment: I put a button on the form with the code as below but get an error saying "Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name."
FYI the Form Name is F_SalesOrders_ItemsInStock and the 
Record Source: v_ItemsInStock (which is an SQL view)

Comment: Function cmdReserve_Click()
 Dim i As Long
 Dim frm As Form
 Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

 Set frm = Forms![F_SalesOrders_ItemsInStock]
 Set rs = frm.RecordsetClone

 rs.MoveFirst

 rs.Move frm.SelTop - 1

 For i = 1 To frm.SelHeight
   MsgBox rs![ItemID]
   rs.MoveNext
 Next i

End Function